# How to refresh the datatable after editing the row object content in angular?

Tags: angularjs

I have a datatable with help of DTColumnBuilder, DTOptionsBuilder in angular JS. Now I am trying to edit row content in a popup.

After editing the value of the content has been changed in the table list(data will be edited temporarily without communicating server). but edited value is not refreshed in view of the table.

I am new to Angular JS, anybody guide me to achieve this.

```
$scope.organization={};
$scope.dtColumns = [  
DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('salaryComponent.salaryHead').withTitle("Name"),
DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('amount').withTitle("Amount"),
DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('effectiveFrom').withTitle("Effective From"),
DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(null).withTitle('Action').notSortable().renderWith(actionsHtml)];
function actionsHtml(data, type, row, meta) {
   $scope.organization[data.id] = data;
   return  '<button class="btn btn-warning"  ng-click="editOrganization(organization[' + data.id + '])"  aria-label="Remove">'+
                                                            '   <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>' +
                                                            '</button>&nbsp;
```

Popup result:

```
 modalInstance.result.then(function (organization) {
    console.log("ok", organization);
    console.log($scope.organization);
}, function () {
     $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Return the new data when you update your row and override it in the 'parent' controller, so that you'll have a refreshed data.
2. Have a service which contains all of your needed data in your table. Then update it when you update a data in your popup. Then it'll refresh your parent view as well, since it'll be a reference to your array/object.

Comment: I tried to edit my data in my pop up, its saved. when i see my console, it is showing that edited value, but that edited value is not updating in the view.       Again i am editing that same object that time i am getting a edited object. In the table view is not updating

Comment: as far as I saw you are passing only an id for your popup handler

Comment: I am passing row object to the pop

Comment: did you try wrapping it when you change with $scope.$apply() ?